# Change python font to tex keeping ticks labels ordinary font

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I would like to set the lsatex font for my plots with the usual rc parameters setting, but I would like to keep the original font only for the labels (that means I don't want numbers to be displayed in math mode).
Actually I have a logarithmic scale.

The standard python font I'm referring to is the one in the picture below (while with rc I set the standard font as the Computer Modern)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use the latex font to name your axes while keeping the standard font for your ticks, you can directly use the latex font in the `xlabel` and `ylabel` functions.
The code can then be written as:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N_points=100
x=np.arange(N_points)
y=np.arange(N_points)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylabel(r'$LaTeX\ font\ y-axis$')
plt.xlabel(r'$LaTeX\ font\  x-axis$')
plt.show()
```

And the output of this code gives:

[image]

Comment: This is not really what I was lookign for, since I have the Compueter Modern on the x-y labels, I set it within the rcParams.